# How many subproblems can this recurrence have while still being faster than an initial recurrence?

Tags: algorithm, math, big-o, asymptotic-complexity, recurrence

I'm having some trouble with an asymptotic analysis question :
My Question is to calculate maximum value if 'a' as stated in my question:

```
An Algorith A has running time T(n)= 7T(n/2) + n^2
and Algorith B has running time T' = aT'(n/4) + n^2.
What will be the maximum integer value of 'a' such that algorith B runs 
asymptotically faster than A.
```

How should i find the value of 'a' should i use only algorith concept in this or is their any other way to find out or any solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a great spot to use the Master Theorem.

In the first recurrence, T(n) = 7T(n/2) + n<sup>2</sup>, the Master Theorem, says that

- a = 7
- b = 2
- d = 2

Since log<sub>b</sub> a = log<sub>2</sub> 7 is greater than d = 2, the recurrence solves to T(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>7</sup>).

Now, let's look at T'(n).  Here, we have a unknown, b = 4, and d = 2.  If we have the following conditions holding true:

- log<sub>4</sub>a > 2, and
- log<sub>4</sub>a < log<sub>2</sub> 7

Then the Master Theorem says that T'(n) = Θ(n<sup>log<sub>4</sub>a</sup>) = o(n<sup>log<sub>2</sub>7</sup>) and we're done.  So we need to solve for a.

Doing this gives

> log<sub>4</sub>a < log<sub>2</sub> 7
>
> log<sub>2</sub>a / log<sub>2</sub> 4 < log<sub>2</sub> 7 (using the change of base formula for logs)
>
> log<sub>2</sub> a / 2 < log<sub>2</sub> 7
>
> log<sub>2</sub> a < 2 log <sub>2</sub> 7
>
> log<sub>2</sub> a < log<sub>2</sub> 7<sup>2</sup> (using the power rule for logs)
>
> log<sub>2</sub> a < log<sub>2</sub> 49
>
> a < 49

Therefore, the largest integral a you can pick is 48.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Solve the equations to get a non-recursive runtime formula